# Assembly Language ESI Pointer

Tags: assembly, stack, runtime, cpu-registers

I know that ESI can hold anything that is 32 bits storage space. How come ESI can hold the address of this array? Isn't the address of this array only 8 bits because array points to the first element in the entire array?

p.s. when you push onto a runtime stack, does the computer first decrement the stack by 2 or 4 depending on the register/memmory operand? OR does it add it to the stack then decrement?

[image]

Comment: The address of a label has nothing to do with the kind of data that you've stored at that address. The `push` instruction decrements the stack pointer before writing to the stack.

Comment: if I wanted to save ESI, and ECX, i would do:
push ESI
push ECX
and then  pop ECX 
and pop ESI, right?
what if I had pushed another value onto the stack after the push ECX? Then this method would not work, correct?

Comment: _"what if I had pushed another value onto the stack after the push ECX? "_ Then you need to pop that value off the stack before you pop `ECX`.

Comment: or instead of popping the extra values, you could just add an immediate constant to ESP equal to the size of the extra values pushed onto the stack. This is typically how ESP is restored after pushing parameters for a call to a function, just after the call to the function. Within a function, ESP is often saved to EBP in a function prologue, so it's just restored from EBP at the function epilogue.